# Three.js react js/next js duplicated content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, next.js

I am using Three.js in react(next js) and a Mesh I have created is duplicated multiple times

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';


function Index() {
    if (process.browser) {
        const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        const camera = new THREE.
            PerspectiveCamera(
                75, 
                window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
                0.1, 
                1000
            );

        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        console.log(scene.children);
        const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
        const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(cube);
        console.log(scene.children);
        camera.position.z = 12;

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        return <div> </div>
    }
    return null;

}

export default Index;
```

Like so:

[image: website]

Then console tab has:

[image: console tab]

The aim is to have 1 cube on the screen without the scrolling(both horrizontal and vertical).

I suspect it's down to document.body.appendChild, I haven't found an alternate method instead of this either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to keep effectful stuff in React's [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect). This will run on the browser when the component mounts and re-run if its dependency array changes. A dependency would be an immutable value that represents state derived from hooks like [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate).

You also never want to touch the DOM directly as React won't know of changes you've made there, leading to duplication and other side effects. Instead, you access the DOM with refs via the [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook. This lets us get a mutable accessor to the canvas with `canvasRef.current`.

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

function Index() {
  const canvasRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      75,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      0.1,
      1000
    );

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvasRef.current });

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

    console.log(scene.children);
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);
    console.log(scene.children);
    camera.position.z = 12;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    // Cleanup on unmount, otherwise stuff will linger in GPU
    return () => {
      renderer.forceContextLoss();
      renderer.dispose();
      cube.geometry.dispose();
      cube.material.dispose();
    };
  }, []);

  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} />;
}

export default Index;
```

Notice how the effect returns a callback. This is a cleanup function that is executed when the component unmounts. We do this because three.js uploads geometry and material shader programs to the GPU, which aren't garbage collected and will linger. As you'd have to manage lifecycle yourself, I'd highly recommend using a renderer for three.js like [`@react-three/fiber`](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber) so you can better use the React ecosystem.

```
import { Canvas } from '@react-three-fiber';

function Index() {
  return (
    <Canvas frameloop="demand" camera={{ position: [0, 0, 12] }}>
      <mesh>
        <boxGeometry />
        <meshBasicMaterial color={0x00ff00} />
      </mesh>
    </Canvas>
  );
}

export default Index;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the script runs whenever the component renders. So the best way to do this is to make a canvas element and use the `useEffect` hook or the `componentDidMount` method if it's a class.

But personally, I'd recommend using `react-three/fiber` or or `react-three-next`